# UDP addresses in html5

Tags: html, html5-video

I am a newbie to html5 and i was trying to include a UDP stream(UDPaddress:port) within the video tag. Is this possible. If so how can we do this?

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer:** No, browsers generally don't support UDP.

**Long answer:** The [chapter on the `video` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#video) in the standards states that the `src` attribute must contain [valid non-empty URL potentially surrounded by spaces](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/urls.html#valid-non-empty-url-potentially-surrounded-by-spaces), which in effect means that it must contain an [URI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) or [IRI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987).
While there is nothing in these specs that say UDP is unsupported ([page 22 of the URI RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-22) explicitly says the URI scheme should contain information on this), and while certain software such as VLC support the `udp://` URI scheme, I don't know of any browser supporting this.