# Reading from udp port in browser

Tags: javascript, html, tcp, udp, websocket

Aside from Java Applet, is there anyway we can read from an UDP socket?
I know websockets are TCP sockets, but I need to communicate with a server via udp sockets, anything in HTML5, or anything at all?
I have looked at this post from: [two years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7264660/udp-addresses-in-html5) and this one as well again from  [two years ago no UDP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657033/javascript-websockets-with-udp).
I was wondering if there is any new way now that we are in 2013 to use the browser to communicate with a server via udp socket?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What you are looking for can't be done with in Javascript due to security constraints such as Distributed Denial of Service (DDOS) attacks. The closest technology available (that I know of) for client-side JS is [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/).

With WebRTC you can use DataChannels over [SRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Real-time_Transport_Protocol) and ICE as a possible solution.

See Also:

- [How to send a UDP Packet with Web RTC - Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216785/how-to-send-a-udp-packet-with-web-rtc-javascript)
- [Can I use WebRTC to open a UDP connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811854/can-i-use-webrtc-to-open-a-udp-connection)

Answer (score 10):

You can use both TCP and UDP connections with the [chrome.socket API](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket.html), but this is only for [Packaged Apps](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps.html) (i.e. apps that are bundled in a container to be run as desktop apps).

The API was available for a while for Chrome extensions, when it was in experimental status (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12163180/483260), from [a user who works at Google](https://stackoverflow.com/users/343108/mihai-parparita) and was [co-presenter for Packaged Apps at Google I/O 2012](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j8oFAr1YR-0))

Comment: Is the socket API only intended for sending text through UDP or could you use this API to playback multicast video as well?

Comment: Google just announced that they will remove Apps: http://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html