# Is it possible to create a Google Cast Sender application using HTML5 and javascript only?

Tags: javascript, google-cast, chromecast

Can the Sender-Receiver communication in a cast sender application be implemented in pure javascript and run inside browser?

Is the API only available for android and iOS?

Comment: This was closed as 'opinion based' but it's not an opinion-type question, it's 'is this possible' rather than 'is it a good idea' or such. And the answer is: it's possible (at least in 2020, probably not in 2013) ref https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need to be able to read from the UDP port used to execute the M-SEARCH query in your multicast domain.  No way as far as I know.  This might change if Google decides to utilize another discovery protocol in addition to DIAL.

http://www.dial-multiscreen.org/

[Reading from udp port in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605252/reading-from-udp-port-in-browser)

Comment: Using the Chrome browser, you can create a Sender application using only JavaScript: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender