# Js development for chrome cast

Tags: google-cast

There is a way to make an app to send content to chrome cast outside of google chrome like IE or Mozilla , or Mobile web browsers?

I just wanna make an app for windows phone, and I see that C# is not supported but I wanna try  js development

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533369/is-there-anything-preventing-a-google-cast-sender-application-being-implementet/18537396#18537396

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe this is officially supported.  The ChromeCast Chrome Extension is required because it injects the JavaScript API into the page when the data-cast-api-enabled="true" is included on the page.  (When using the JavaScript API you don't include a *.js file.

Comment: Thanks anyway :)
I'll wait