# Reading UDP Packets from PHP with my browser

Tags: php, sockets

I tried to make a php script to reading udp packets from browser but I just make one that only I can use it with cmd with ( php filename.php ), my question is how I can read the same way from my browser to get packets!

my php script I use:

```
<?php

//Reduce errors
error_reporting(~E_WARNING);

//Create a UDP socket
if(!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Socket created \n";

// Bind the source address
if( !socket_bind($sock, "127.0.0.1" , 2223) )
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Could not bind socket : [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

echo "Socket bind OK \n";

//Do some communication, this loop can handle multiple clients
while(1)
{
    echo "Waiting for data ... \n";

    //Receive some data
    $r = socket_recvfrom($sock, $buf, 512, 0, $remote_ip, $remote_port);
    echo $buf;

    //echo "$remote_ip : $remote_port -- " . $buf;

    //Send back the data to the client
    //socket_sendto($sock, "OK " . $buf , 100 , 0 , $remote_ip , $remote_port);
}

socket_close($sock);
?>
```

Comment: Javascript can help.  http://socket.io/

Comment: so, only way is javascript i think ? or i must have both php file and javascript as client to read it ?

Comment: So what will host a runtime for this php script?

Comment: i have already made java script to send packets, and i just want to read it from browser.. @Deryck send me a good web site.. but i also need an example how to read UDP packets on an example port, thnx !.

Comment: see here for the UDP side of things: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605252/reading-from-udp-port-in-browser

Comment: so to work with sockets i need javascript ? php cant do this since is a server side programing language ?