# UPnP discovery, description inside Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, upnp

I am looking to get UPnP device discovery, description done in Javascript - either in standalone browser environment or in NodeJS
Towards that, I tried below two solutions but both did not work for me. Details -

1]NodeJS bases:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/upnp-client
After correcting few typos in the example app, and running it in node (My nodeJS is running under X-Ubuntu Virtual Machine inside Virtualbox)
I get below errors on running the upnp-client example app

**dgram.js:399
    throw new errnoException(process._errno, 'addMembership');**
          ^
**Error: addMembership EBADF
    at new errnoException (dgram.js:457:11)**

NodeJS version: v0.10.25
Upnp client api: 0.0.1

2]Under Browser(Chrome/IE)
https://www.npmjs.com/package/upnp-client
None of them at the versions I have supported the navigator.getNetworkServices API which seems to be needed for this library

How can i get UPnP device discovery working in Javascript?

Any other solutions or pointers to resolve above errors/workarounds appreciated.

Comment: [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_network) and [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TCP_Socket_API) both provides socket API for extensions. You may check if there is existing UPnP client implemented as extension.

Answer (score 2):

[UPnP uses TCP/UDP packages for advertisement/discovery/etc.](http://upnp.org/specs/arch/UPnP-arch-DeviceArchitecture-v1.1.pdf) And since [browsers cannot open network sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17605252/2295964), the short answer is: **No. We can't use UPnP in a browser at the moment**.

The only glimmer of hope is the [Network Service Discovery](http://www.w3.org/TR/discovery-api/), which is still in development phase in most of the browsers. In Chrome for example you could enable it using `chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features`, and then would be able to do something like this (from W3C draft):

```js
function showServices( services ) {
  // Show a list of all the services provided to the web page
  for(var i = 0, l = services.length; i < l; i++) console.log( services[i].name );
}

navigator.getNetworkServices('zeroconf:_boxee-jsonrpc._tcp').then(showServices);
```

Comment: still does not work in chrome. would be great if it did.